# XML parsing Python (when need to specify 3 tags and 1 attribute)

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, dom, getelementsbytagname

In the below xml cut from the longer xml at the bottom, how do I specifically search within "CrntRgstns" then "BrnchOfLocs" then "BrnchOfLoc " then "str1" to get "13A MAIN ST" as the output.

```
</CrntRgstns>
<BrnchOfLocs>
<BrnchOfLoc str1="13A MAIN ST"/>
```

The code below gets the desired output, **but I need all those criteria (i.e. "CrntRgstns" and "BrnchOfLocs") to be specified/included** in the code:

```
p = r'C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Test_File.xml'
xmldoc = minidom.parse(p)
for x in range(0,2000):
    defg = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('BrnchOfLoc')[x].getAttribute('str1')
    print(defg)
```

more extensive xml for 1 individual below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<IAPDIndividualReport GenOn="2021-01-03">
<Indvls>
<Indvl>
<Info lastNm="Modafferi" firstNm="Paul" midNm="Anthony" indvlPK="2762691" actvAGReg="Y" link="https://adviserinfo.sec.gov/individual/summary/2762691"/>
<OthrNms>
<OthrNm lastNm="BIAMONTE" firstNm="PAUL" midNm="F"/>
<OthrNm lastNm="Modafferi" firstNm="Paul" midNm="A"/>
<OthrNm lastNm="Modafferi" firstNm="Paul" midNm="Anthony"/>
</OthrNms>
<CrntEmps>
<CrntEmp orgNm="MERRILL LYNCH, PIERCE, FENNER &amp; SMITH INCORPORATED" orgPK="7691" str1="ONE BRYANT PARK" city="NEW YORK" state="NY" cntry="United States" postlCd="10036">
<CrntRgstns>
<CrntRgstn regAuth="NJ" regCat="RA" st="APPROVED" stDt="2019-11-25"/>
</CrntRgstns>
<BrnchOfLocs>
<BrnchOfLoc str1="13A MAIN ST" city="SPARTA" state="NJ" cntry="United States" postlCd="07871"/>
</BrnchOfLocs>
</CrntEmp>
</CrntEmps>
<Exms>
<Exm exmCd="S63" exmNm="Uniform Securities Agent State Law Examination" exmDt="1996-11-15"/>
<Exm exmCd="S65" exmNm="Uniform Investment Adviser Law Examination" exmDt="1997-03-06"/>
</Exms>
<Dsgntns/>
<PrevRgstns>
<PrevRgstn orgNm="AMERIPRISE FINANCIAL SERVICES, LLC" orgPK="6363" regBeginDt="2018-06-22" regEndDt="2019-03-26">
<BrnchOfLocs>
<BrnchOfLoc city="Franklin" state="NJ"/>
</BrnchOfLocs>
```

Comment: Please provide a well-formed sample XML file. And if you get the desired output, what is the problem?

Comment: There are other occurrences when the "Sample_Tag1" appears without the "Sample_Header1" or "Sample_Header2" and I don't want to return those results.

Comment: For dealing with xml, you should use xml tools such as xpath, if available.

Comment: Your linked XML does not match your question.

Comment: Now the linked XML matches. Apologies, I was trying to make it simpler.

Comment: @JackFleeting, what is the xpath that would accomplish what I'm looking for? Is it this: "CrntRgstns/BrnchOfLocs/BrnchOfLoc/str1"

Comment: @mzjn, I just included a representative XML sample in the question.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you are asking, but the xpath to get `13A MAIN ST` should be something like `//BrnchOfLocs//BrnchOfLoc/@str1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some XPATH needed and [lxml](https://pypi.org/project/lxml/)...

```py
from lxml import etree
from io import BytesIO

data = b'''\
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<IAPDIndividualReport GenOn="2021-01-03">
    <Indvls>
        <Indvl>
            <Info lastNm="Modafferi" firstNm="Paul" midNm="Anthony" indvlPK="2762691" actvAGReg="Y" link="https://adviserinfo.sec.gov/individual/summary/2762691"/>
            <OthrNms>
                <OthrNm lastNm="BIAMONTE" firstNm="PAUL" midNm="F"/>
                <OthrNm lastNm="Modafferi" firstNm="Paul" midNm="A"/>
                <OthrNm lastNm="Modafferi" firstNm="Paul" midNm="Anthony"/>
            </OthrNms>
            <CrntEmps>
                <CrntEmp orgNm="MERRILL LYNCH, PIERCE, FENNER &amp; SMITH INCORPORATED" orgPK="7691" str1="ONE BRYANT PARK" city="NEW YORK" state="NY" cntry="United States" postlCd="10036">
                    <CrntRgstns>
                        <CrntRgstn regAuth="NJ" regCat="RA" st="APPROVED" stDt="2019-11-25"/>
                    </CrntRgstns>
                    <BrnchOfLocs>
                        <BrnchOfLoc str1="13A MAIN ST" city="SPARTA" state="NJ" cntry="United States" postlCd="07871"/>
                    </BrnchOfLocs>
                </CrntEmp>
            </CrntEmps>
            <Exms>
                <Exm exmCd="S63" exmNm="Uniform Securities Agent State Law Examination" exmDt="1996-11-15"/>
                <Exm exmCd="S65" exmNm="Uniform Investment Adviser Law Examination" exmDt="1997-03-06"/>
            </Exms>
            <Dsgntns/>
            <PrevRgstns>
                <PrevRgstn orgNm="AMERIPRISE FINANCIAL SERVICES, LLC" orgPK="6363" regBeginDt="2018-06-22" regEndDt="2019-03-26">
                    <BrnchOfLocs>
                        <BrnchOfLoc city="Franklin" state="NJ"/>
                    </BrnchOfLocs>
                </PrevRgstn>
                <PrevRgstn orgNm="CITIGROUP GLOBAL MARKETS INC." orgPK="7059" regBeginDt="2004-12-03" regEndDt="2005-09-26">
                    <BrnchOfLocs>
                        <BrnchOfLoc city="MILFORD" state="PA"/>
                        <BrnchOfLoc city="LITTLE FALLS" state="NJ"/>
                        <BrnchOfLoc city="MILFORD" state="PA"/>
                        <BrnchOfLoc city="GOSHEN" state="NY"/>
                    </BrnchOfLocs>
                </PrevRgstn>
                <PrevRgstn orgNm="MERRILL LYNCH, PIERCE, FENNER &amp; SMITH INCORPORATED" orgPK="7691" regBeginDt="1999-11-05" regEndDt="2004-12-07">
                    <BrnchOfLocs>
                        <BrnchOfLoc city="SPARTA" state="NJ"/>
                    </BrnchOfLocs>
                </PrevRgstn>
                <PrevRgstn orgNm="INVESTMENT PROFESSIONALS, INC." orgPK="30184" regBeginDt="2016-06-07" regEndDt="2018-09-24">
                    <BrnchOfLocs>
                        <BrnchOfLoc city="SAN ANTONIO" state="TX"/>
                        <BrnchOfLoc city="Franklin" state="NJ"/>
                        <BrnchOfLoc city="Danville" state="KY"/>
                    </BrnchOfLocs>
                </PrevRgstn>
                <PrevRgstn orgNm="SORRENTO PACIFIC FINANCIAL, LLC" orgPK="127787" regBeginDt="2008-07-15" regEndDt="2016-06-02">
                    <BrnchOfLocs>
                        <BrnchOfLoc city="FRANKLIN" state="NJ"/>
                        <BrnchOfLoc city="FRANKLIN" state="NJ"/>
                    </BrnchOfLocs>
                </PrevRgstn>
            </PrevRgstns>
            <EmpHss>
                <EmpHs fromDt="06/2008" toDt="06/2016" orgNm="SORRENTO PACIFIC FINANCIAL, LLC" city="SAN DIEGO" state="CA"/>
                <EmpHs fromDt="06/2008" toDt="06/2016" orgNm="SUSSEX BANK" city="AUGUSTA" state="NJ"/>
                <EmpHs fromDt="06/2016" toDt="06/2019" orgNm="Ameriprise" city="Minneapolis" state="MN"/>
                <EmpHs fromDt="06/2016" toDt="11/2019" orgNm="Investment Professionals, Inc." city="San Antonio" state="TX"/>
                <EmpHs fromDt="11/2019" orgNm="MERRILL LYNCH, PIERCE, FENNER &amp; SMITH INCORPORATED" city="SPARTA" state="NJ"/>
                <EmpHs fromDt="12/2019" orgNm="BANK OF AMERICA, N.A" city="Sparta" state="NJ"/>
            </EmpHss>
            <OthrBuss/>
            <DRPs>
                <DRP hasRegAction="N" hasCriminal="N" hasBankrupt="N" hasCivilJudc="N" hasBond="N" hasJudgment="Y" hasInvstgn="N" hasCustComp="N" hasTermination="N"/>
            </DRPs>
        </Indvl>
    </Indvls>
</IAPDIndividualReport>
'''

f = BytesIO(data)
tree = etree.parse(f)
for e in tree.xpath('.//CrntRgstns/following-sibling::BrnchOfLocs/BrnchOfLoc'):
    print(e.attrib['str1'])
```

Comment: instead of the "data =" that you have to get my data I used data = r'C:\Users\Andrew\Test_File.xml'. However, I get this error, "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'". How do I resolve this? Thanks!

Comment: You're supposed to use `f = open(r'C:\Users\Andrew\Test_File.xml')`. The BytesIO stuff was just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: say there's another "<BrnchOfLoc" (aka another address) directly below the first one. How do I only return the first one?

Comment: Am away from my PC but you can try `tree.xpath('.//CrntRgstns/following-sibling::BrnchOfLocs/BrnchOfLoc[1]')`